# How to get the date that files were added to TFS

Tags: c#, command-line, tfs

For a particular branch I'd like to generate a list of file names and the date that they were originally added to TFS. I don't really mind what method I use to get it, but command line or C# solutions would be great. I haven't included anything that I've tried because I don't really know where to start!

I'm trying to get a result something like this:

```
Date added     File name
========================
10/02/2015     File1.txt
16/05/2015     File2.txt
19/08/2014     File3.txt
```

Comment: Here's a neat little tool that does what you want : https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/70C4CAF6-40E5-4A46-AAFD-858544C3A7DD

Comment: @JonathanCarroll I've had a look at that, but I can't see how to find out what I'm looking for. Can you tell me how to find the date the file was added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this can be done, but I don't know how well this will perform, it probably depends on the size of you code base.

Using the `VersionControlServer` on the TFS API I'm getting all the items and then for each item querying the history to get the first changeset and then getting the details:

```
    void Main()
{
    const String CollectionAddress = "http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection";

    using (var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(CollectionAddress)))
    {
        tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
        var server = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

        server.GetItems(
            path: "$/Code/",
            version: VersionSpec.Latest,
            recursion: RecursionType.Full,
            deletedState: DeletedState.NonDeleted,
            itemType: ItemType.File)
        .Items
        .Select(
            item =>
                server
                .GetBranchHistory(
                    itemSpecs: new[] { new ItemSpec(item.ServerItem, RecursionType.None), },
                    version: VersionSpec.Latest)
                .Single()
                .Select(
                    a =>
                        new
                        {
                            a.Relative.BranchToItem.ChangesetId,
                            a.Relative.BranchToItem.CheckinDate,
                            a.Relative.BranchToItem.ServerItem,
                        })
                .Single())
        .Dump(5);
    }
}
```

You can download a working Linqpad Script from [here](http://share.linqpad.net/ghb3d5.linq) - targeting VS2013 object model.

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Unfortunately it's giving me the date that the file was branched rather than the date the original file was added to TFS. Is it possible to update the script to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by branched? Are you running this on your Main branch? Is it showing the date something was merged into Main instead of the date it was created in branch?

Comment: I'm running it on a dev branch. I can't merge dev into main at the moment, so I have to run it on dev. If the file was added since the dev branch was created I get the correct date. If the file existed when the branch was created, I get the date that the branch from main occurred.

Comment: @sclarke81 I've updated my answer, no idea if this works correctly, I feel like it shouldn't, but it passes all the simple tests I tried.

Comment: This does just what I was looking for. Thanks very much! I made one small change which was to replace `a.Relative.BranchToItem.ServerItem` with `item.ServerItem`. With this change you get the present file name rather than the name and location when the file was added.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN TFS History command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxtbh4yh.aspx) it seems you can run the below command from Visual Studio command prompt which will get you the change set files for a particular day

```
tf history "local path" /version:D2015-09-03 /recursive /noprompt
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that doesn't do what I'm looking for. What you've posted gives a list of changesets. What I'd like is a list of all of the files with the date that each file was first added to TFS.

Comment: @sclarke81, can you be little more specific. do you mean, you want to get all files on a particular day for a particular folder in TFS?

Comment: I've added an example showing the kind of output I'd like. So for all files within a branch I'd like to print out a list of the file name with the date that the file was first added to TFS.

Comment: @sclarke81, then my posted answer will do the trick. Go through the MSDN document link in answer and it has few examples showing the same.